# Show/hide not working during AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, hide, show

I have a function that requests data using ajax. I would like to display a busy spinner but hide/show do not change the elements visibility.

```
function RequestDataFromServer(stuff, url) {
    var result;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { stuff: Stuff},
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#divOverlay").show();
            console.log("Starting...");
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#divOverlay").hide();
            console.log("Complete!");
            result = true;
        },
        success: function (data) {
            AddDataToCache(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            result = false;
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

I know the show/hide syntax is correct because it works when I attach it to buttons. I have also tried using :

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $("#divOverlay").show();
})
```

With no affect (however if I step thru this event in Chrome it does show and hide the elements). I've also tried show/hide in a function that calls the RequestDataFromServer function... still nothing. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Make sure the element you target has the id `divOverlay`..

Comment: Are your console log messages showing? Is your ajax operation actually taking a while to run or is it over very quickly and so there's no time to see the overlay?

Comment: @Zakaria - The ids are correct, I tested it with a button and the element show correctly.

Comment: @J. Schmale - Yes, the console messages are showing correctly. The ajax takes a few seconds so it should be noticeable.

Answer (score 4):

I tested this, and `.show()` and `.hide()` work in my ajax calls just fine. I'm guessing you have some syntax errors that are causing this. Let's do some housekeeping.

First, as others have mentioned, make the element that you are trying to show is accessible in the DOM. This is the most common omission IMO. I presume you have an element such as:

```
<div id="divOverlay" style="display:none;">Something</div>
```

Second, variables are case sensitive. Make sure the variable `stuff` is lower case when passed as `data: {stuff: stuff}`.

Third, it's worth noting that `complete` is called after both `success` or `error`, and therefore your `result = true` should really be defined in `success` rather than `complete`.

[image: Ajax Process Flow]

```
function RequestDataFromServer(stuff, url) {
  var result;

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {stuff: stuff},
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
      $("#divOverlay").show();
      console.log("Starting...");
    },
    complete: function () {
      $("#divOverlay").hide();
      console.log("Complete!");
    },
    success: function (data) {
      AddDataToCache(data);
      result = true;
    },
    error: function () {
      result = false;
    }
  });

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue , it worked when async:true. Still don't know the cause but it worked.

Comment: Don't know the point in using the deprecated `async:true` for ajax, the whole idea of ajax is that it is asynchronous. Definitely not a good/recommended answer

Comment: Even in other blogs they recommended to add async:true instead .But no one have described the reason why. and my main issue was if i add 3 lines
of code in beforeSend section. 1st line is executed and the third line is executed but not the 2nd line.

Answer (score 0):

well try this use in your divOverlay css display : none ; 
this work too.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
            $("#divOverlay").css("display", "block");
        });
```

you have in your ajax

```
beforeSend: function () {
            $("#divOverlay").show();
            console.log("Starting...");
```

this means " show my div before send my ajx" You wrote 2 times the same instruction.
Choose one and remove the other.

Comment: Tried it, still no go. I also tried taking out the $("#divOverlay").hide(); on Complete to see if the Show was doing anything. It does, it shows after the ajax request is complete... even though the console messages show correctly. Ugh...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove `async: false;` from your and also remove `beforeSend` code, then try. As I have done in the below code, just need to place it in your code.

```
function RequestDataFromServer(stuff, url) {
    var result;
    $("#divOverlay").show();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { stuff: Stuff},
        //async: false,
        //beforeSend: function () {
            //$("#divOverlay").show();
            //console.log("Starting...");
        //},
        complete: function () {
            $("#divOverlay").hide();
            console.log("Complete!");
            result = true;
        },
        success: function (data) {
            AddDataToCache(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            result = false;
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```